# Xamarin iOS Firebase Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, analytics, firebase-analytics

I don't understand how to log event with array items in parameters.

For example, if I need to log something like EventNamesConstants.Login I can to do

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<object, object> {
  ParameterNamesConstants.Method, "Google" }
};
Analytics.LogEvent(EventNamesConstants.Login, parameters);
```

But now I need to log `EventNamesConstants.ViewItem`
And one of parameters is array of items where item has a name.
When I try to do something like that

```
var items = new[]{
new Dictionary<object, object> {
ParameterNamesConstants.ItemName, title }
     }
 };
 
 var parameters = new Dictionary<object, object> {
   ParameterNamesConstants.Currency, currencyCode },
   ParameterNamesConstants.Value, value },
   ParameterNamesConstants.Items, items }
 };
```

I got an error.
I tried to find examples, but they didn't have an array.
I am so sorry.

An error is:

> Do not know how to marshal object of type

```
 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object][]'
 to an NSObject
```

And func Analytics.LogEvent of Firebase is:

```
public static void LogEvent (string name, Dictionary<object, object>? parameters) 
{   
 LogEvent (name, (parameters == null) ? null :
 ((parameters!.Keys.Count == 0) ? new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>
 () : NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys
 (parameters!.Values.ToArray (), parameters!.Keys.ToArray (),
 nint.op_Implicit (parameters!.Keys.Count)))); 
}
```

Help me please.

Comment: Please add to your post which error it throw.

Comment: I added an error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could try the following way to create your parameters,

```
var keys = new NSObject[]
{
    new NSString(ItemName),

};

var objects = new NSObject[]
{ 
    new NSString(title),

};

NSDictionary dicionary = new NSDictionary<NSObject, NSObject>(keys, objects);

NSArray items =  NSArray.FromNSObjects(dicionary);

var parameters = new Dictionary<object, object>
{
    { ParameterNamesConstants.Currency, currencyCode },
    { ParameterNamesConstants.Value, value },
    { ParameterNamesConstants.Items, items }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use also Firebase Analytics in my apps.

Here is a suitable extension method on `IDictionary<string, string>` that anyone can use to convert easily C# `IDictionary` to iOS `NSDictionary`

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an <see cref="IDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> of string key-value pairs to an <see cref="NSDictionary"/> of <see cref="NSString"/> keys and <see cref="NSObject"/> values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dictionary">The dictionary to convert. Cannot be null.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="NSDictionary"/> with <see cref="NSString"/> keys and <see cref="NSObject"/> values corresponding to the entries in the input dictionary.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown if the input dictionary is null.</exception>
/// <remarks>
/// This method iterates over the input dictionary to create a pair of arrays for keys and values, which are then used to construct the NSDictionary.
/// It's designed to be used as an extension method for any IDictionary&lt;string, string&gt; instance.
/// Note: Null keys or values in the input dictionary will result in exceptions, as <see cref="NSString"/> cannot be instantiated with a null reference.
/// </remarks>
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// var myDict = new Dictionary&lt;string, string&gt; { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } };
/// var nsDict = myDict.ToNSDictionary();
/// </code>
/// </example>
public static NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject> ToNSDictionary(this IDictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dictionary);

    var keysAndValues = dictionary
        .Select(kv => (Key: new NSString(kv.Key), Value: new NSString(kv.Value)))
        .ToArray();

    var keys = keysAndValues
        .Select(kv => kv.Key)
        .ToArray();

    var values = keysAndValues
        .Select(kv => kv.Value)
        .ToArray();

    return new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(keys, values);
}
```

If you need, here is another one on `IDictionary<string, object>`

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an <see cref="IDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> of string key-value pairs to an <see cref="NSDictionary"/> of <see cref="NSString"/> keys and <see cref="NSObject"/> values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dictionary">The dictionary to convert. Cannot be null.</param>
/// <returns>An <see cref="NSDictionary"/> with <see cref="NSString"/> keys and <see cref="NSObject"/> values corresponding to the entries in the input dictionary.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown if the input dictionary is null.</exception>
/// <remarks>
/// This method iterates over the input dictionary to create a pair of arrays for keys and values, which are then used to construct the NSDictionary.
/// It's designed to be used as an extension method for any IDictionary&lt;string, object&gt; instance.
/// Note: Null keys or values in the input dictionary will result in exceptions, as <see cref="NSString"/> cannot be instantiated with a null reference.
/// </remarks>
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// var myDict = new Dictionary&lt;string, object&gt; { { "key1", object1 }, { "key2", object2 } };
/// var nsDict = myDict.ToNSDictionary();
/// </code>
/// </example>
public static NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject> ToNSDictionary(this IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dictionary);

    var keys = dictionary.Keys
        .Select(arg => new NSString(arg))
        .ToArray();

    var objects = dictionary.Values
        .Select(NSObject.FromObject)
        .ToArray();

    return new NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>(keys, objects);
}
```

FYI: I use `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` => Only available since C#10, use classic way if you are under C#10.